# Getting Tweets in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter

I am trying to load tweets but my code isn't working when using my MVC app. However, the exact code works when using a console.

I am asuming it is something to do with "async", I have not had experience using this before and I am unable to find a solution. Break points after "GetAccessToken()" are not hit

In my Controler:

```
    public ActionResult Tweets(int tweets, string username)
    {
        var twitter = new Twitter();

        var userTweets = twitter.GetTweets("chrishall9521", 10).Result.ToList();

        this.ViewBag.Tweets = userTweets;

        return View();
    }
```

In my "Twitter" class:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetTweets(string userName, int count)
    {
        var accessToken = await GetAccessToken();
        var requestUserTimeline = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count={0}&screen_name={1}&trim_user=1&exclude_replies=1", count, userName));
        requestUserTimeline.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage responseUserTimeLine = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestUserTimeline);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic json = serializer.Deserialize<object>(await responseUserTimeLine.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        var enumerableTwitts = (json as IEnumerable<dynamic>);

        if (enumerableTwitts == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return enumerableTwitts.Select(t => (string)(t["text"].ToString()));
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token ");
        var customerInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(OAuthConsumerKey + ":" + OAuthConsumerSecret));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + customerInfo);
        request.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

        string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(json);
        return item["access_token"];
    }
```

Comment: @eh. that works! Cheers mate, massive help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.Result` like that - you're deadlocking. Use `await` in the `Tweets` method instead and make it `async`. The basic "golden rule" for using `async` is that when you use it, you use it all the way up the chain.

Here's a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) with similar examples for further reading.